# API response in Laravel decode issue

Tags: php, json, rest, laravel-5

i have the following route:

```
Route::get('/verifica-dominio', function() {
$dom = Input::get('dominio');
$dominio = explode('.', Input::get('dominio'));
$name= $dominio[0];
$tld = $dominio[1];
$url =  'https://api.cloudns.net/domains/check-available.json?auth-id=1243&auth-password=KNK-dn5.&name=' . $name . '&tld[]=' . $tld;
$json = file_get_contents($url, true, stream_context_create(['socket' => ['bindto' => '0:0']]));
$j = json_decode($json);
return var_dump($j);
```

});

it return this object

```
object(stdClass)#1023 (1) { ["provola.com"]=> object(stdClass)#1024 (1) { ["status"]=> int(0) } }
```

how i can got status=1 in my code?

Comment: you shouldn't return var_dump ... code it how your supposed!

Comment: Try this `$array = get_object_vars($j); var_dump(array);` and see what youget !!

Comment: of course json offer this response {"provola.com":{"status":0}} but if i try to extract 0 from status got ILLEGAL STRING error

Comment: @Maraboc return this array(1) { ["provola.com"]=> object(stdClass)#1024 (1) { ["status"]=> int(0) } }

Comment: Then you can access status like this : `$array[$tld]->status` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `TRUE` as the second argument to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to make it decode the JSON to arrays and not to objects:

```
$j = json_decode($json, TRUE);
print_r($j);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [provola.com] => Array
        (
            [status] => 0
        )
)
```

Now everything became much clearer and easier to handle. `$j['pravola.com']['status']` is the value you are looking for.

If it is not more clear then read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and insist on the ["Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) section.

I guess the key `'pravola.com'` is what you pass to the remote API in argument `tld`. If this is the case then you can use `$j[$tld]['status']` to get the data you need.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `json_decode()` , its takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

```
$j = json_decode($json, TRUE);
print_r($j);
```

and your php section you can use php array to you can process data

this is common format

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

and this output is :

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [e] => 5
)
```

for more information

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php